# nextjs 13 VSC debugger not working together with docker

Tags: docker, next.js, next.js13

Using visual studio code for debugging my nextjs 13 project inside a docker container does not work.
I am using a node:tls container, started with "NODE_OPTIONS='--inspect=0.0.0.0' next dev". The port 9229 is configured for debugger.

My launch.json looks like this:

```
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "type": "node",
      "request": "attach",
      "restart": true,
      "name": "next.js",
      "address": "localhost",
      "localRoot": "${workspaceFolder}/apps/app",
      "remoteRoot": "/usr/src/app",
      "protocol": "inspector",
      "trace": true,
      "skipFiles": ["<node_internals>/**"],
      "port": 9229,
      "sourceMaps": true
    }
  ]
}
```

The code outside the container is at /apps/app .
The code inside the container is at /usr/src/app .

Strangly the debugger attaches but it runs over each breakpoint without stopping.

[image]

What am I doing wrong? The localRoot and remoteRoot are okay.
I tried starting the code with --inspect-brk and that actually broke at the first line of code.
Any hints are very very welcome!

Comment: i am having the same issue. did you figure out a solution to this?

Comment: nope ...........

Comment: man what a bummer. i think maybe it has to do with source maps. did you go down that path?